# Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'world' is less accessible than field 'frmSplashScreen

Tags: c#, field, restriction

I have this error called Inconsistent accessibility:

> field type 'world' is less accessible than field 'frmSplashScreen'

In my code there is a public partial class called `frmSplashScreen`

There is also a public class called `world`

The line that caused the error was:

```
private world currentWorld;
```

The above line is in the class `frmSplashScreen`

What is causing the problem?

Comment: Can you show more of the actual code? Judging from the error message the `frmSplashScreen` class is not actually public, or not actually a class...

Comment: Downvoted for not explaining anything and polluting search results

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Generally this happens because your field is `private`. You must change it to `public`:

```
public world currentWorld;
```

For more on this, take a look here: [Restrictions on Using Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx03xt0t.aspx)

Comment: ... you removed your comment, but you got a different error. It's like the first error. You must change `time2Craft` to public.

Comment: Well looks like you have inconsistency throughout your classes' definitions. To help you more I need to see the code and the error messages.

Comment: Wait a long time for what? :)

Comment: for the error to dissapear in the error window in visual studio

Comment: While this would probably remove the error message, it's more of a hotfix than a real solution - the other answer resolves the main issue. But I understand OP didn't really describe his full situation clearly.

Comment: in my case it was the opposite: i had to change from public into private ftw

Answer (score 78):

This can also happen when you have not initialized your class "world" as public

you should do :

```
public class world
```

Instead of :

```
class world
```

Comment: do this for the class and any base class of it

Comment: Take into account that any class is "internal" by default in C#. That is the reason you need to specify "public".
Great answer, by the way.

Comment: This resolved my issue, I was busy staring at the fields that I was returning from the method, not taking into cognizance the class that was being returned.

Answer (score 0):

also , I got such an error with `public` access modifier. The solution was to add `{get;set;}`  getter and setter to properties

Answer (score 0):

you can't use  `private` access specifier in that statement

```
    Public class world
```

will solve this problem