# Inconsistent accessibility field type WinPho8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, singleton

I have this issue in my project.

I have declared a class as a singleton to use it as xml parser. I wanted to return list of pois parsed but I wasn't able to change the return type without getting an error so I tried to declared a global variable to read it from other classes but I am receiving this error.

```
namespace XML_Parser
{
    public sealed class XMLParserPOI_Wiki
    {
        private List<POI> places;

        private static readonly XMLParserPOI_Wiki uniqueInstance = new XMLParserPOI_Wiki();

        public List<POI> getPlaces()
        {
            return places;
        }

        //Constructor
        private XMLParserPOI_Wiki(){
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Constructor singleton created");
        }

        public static XMLParserPOI_Wiki getInstance()
        {
            return uniqueInstance;
        }

        public void parseWikitude(string url)
        {
            places = null;
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));


        }

        private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);
                XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";
                XNamespace ns2 = "http://www.openarml.org/wikitude/1.0";
                var placemarkers = xdoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Placemark");

                places =
                (....).ToList();



            }
        }

    }
}
```

complete error is:

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: 
field type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<XML_Parser.POI>' is 
less accessible than field 
'XML_Parser.XMLParserPOI_Wiki.places'   
C:\Users\vindi_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\XML_Parser\XML_Parser\XMLParserPOI_Wiki.cs 
13  27  XML_Parser
```

Comment: What is the accessibility of POI class? is it public?

Comment: Please consider doing minimal search before asking questions. It is unclear why your one is different from MSDN documentation on the error message and other related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually means that you're exposing internal classes in public members, which is not possible.

I guess the class XML_Parser.POI is not marked as public?

Comment: It is marked as public class POI

Comment: I guess that was the problem. I had to clean project and then it worked. Maybe I added public to POI later and I didn't clean. Thanks man!

Comment: @Biribu Glad I could help. :) Btw, as mentioned in another answer that was deleted, if you plan to do a lot of C# coding, I'd suggest you read a book or something, so that you would know about the features that are at your disposal. For example, in C#, the singleton pattern is normally implemented using a property.

Comment: Thanks. I have to. We still are not developing for Winpho8 but I was doing some trials to see how it works and if I can start to include in my job. I found this singleton in a tutorial. I don't know if it is the best. I will check it.

Comment: How this answer is different/better than many related (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990309/inconsistent-accessibility-field-type-world-is-less-accessible-than-field-fr?rq=1)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I guess it's not. I just saw the question and answered it... you know, trying to be helpful when I can... but I guess that's a bad thing nowadays, sorry.