# Inconsistent accessibility: field type is less accessible than field

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext

I've finally started implementing Linq in our old API so I started making all the classes associated with our Tables and DB classes for the Database I followed an online guid but I can't get it working. I have the following code for my Company.cs:

```
using RAW_API.Models;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace RAW_API.DataContexts {
    [Database]
    public class Company : DataContext {
        public Table<NewsItems> news_items;
        public Company( string connection ) : base( connection ) { }
    }
}
```

And for my NewsItems.cs class file:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace RAW_API.Models {
    [Table( Name = "news_items" )]
    public class NewsItems {
        [Column( IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true )]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string titleNL { get; set; }
        [Column]
        ...
    }
}
```

all classes and fields are public but it still throws the following error:

> Error CS0052: Inconsistent accessibility: field type
>   'Table' is less accessible than field
>   'Company.news_items'  ApplicationServerWrapper    K:\Group\repo_groclaes_rawapi\ApplicationServerWrapper\DataContexts\Company.cs:8

Comment: Where or what is the `Table` type?

Comment: It seems like your `Table` type is not `public`, as your class `NewsItems`. As @rene said, what is your type `Table` and how is it defined? With what access modifier?

Comment: @rene It's the included class from linq, that's what confuses me. 'class System.Data.Linq.Table<TEntity> where TEntity : class'

Answer (score 8):

*Inconsistent accessibility* error means that `Table` class (i.e. `Table<T>`) may declared & initialized as `private`, set it to `public` so that it has same [accessibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/restrictions-on-using-accessibility-levels) as `news_items`.

Hence, if you have `Table` class somewhere like this:

```
// T is the table class name
class Table<T>
{
    // other stuff
}
```

You need to set it as `public` level as required by `news_items` field:

```
public class Table<T>
{
    // other stuff
}
```

Reference:

[Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'world' is less accessible than field 'frmSplashScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990309/inconsistent-accessibility-field-type-world-is-less-accessible-than-field-fr)

Comment: @Icepickle I thought so too, but the error should show `TableAttribute` instead if that was the case.

Comment: `TableAttribute` is different from `Table<T>` in your case... `TableAttribute` is not generic & must be used with `[Table("TableName")]` instead of declared as type.

Comment: If I do that I get this error: 
Error CS1729 'TableAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments NewsAPI K:\Group\repo_groclaes_rawapi\NewsAPI\Models\NewsItems.cs 5 Active

Answer (score 2):

Here from MS DOCs

Compiler Error CS0052 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0052

```
// CS0052.cs
public class MyClass2
{
   // The following line causes an error because the field, M, is declared
   // as public, but the type, MyClass, is private. Therefore the type is
   // less accessible than the field.
public MyClass M;   // CS0052

private class MyClass
{
}
   // One way to resolve the error is to change the accessibility of the type
   // to public. 
   //public class MyClass
   // Another solution is to change the accessibility of the field to private.
   //  private MyClass M; 
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```